# Attempted import error: 'useRouterMatch' is not exported from 'react-router-dom'

Tags: react-router

I have copied the react router ["2nd Example: Nested Routing"](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start) example from the react-router docs in to my app as-is. (The "1st Example: Basic Routing" works fine)

The error I'm getting is `Attempted import error: 'useRouterMatch' is not exported from 'react-router-dom'`

The example references `useRouterMatch` but it doesn't seem to be exported and searching google for 'useRouterMatch' returns no results outside of the example so I'm having a hard time finding docs or anything.

Here are all my react-router dependencies from package.json:

```
    "@types/react-router": "^5.1.1",
    "@types/react-router-bootstrap": "^0.24.5",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^4.3.5",
    "react-router-bootstrap": "^0.24.4",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
```

Comment: Attempted to delete node modules and reinstall but I'm using the latest version [per npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-router-dom) (5.1.2) and grepping `node_modules/react-router-dom` finds no results for `useRouterMatch`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out there were a couple of issues here.

First, there seems to be a typo in the docs (which I've submitted a [PR](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/pull/6988) for)

Second, I probably should have mentioned I'm using Typescript, and after reading a couple of threads, I realized that while I had the latest react-router-dom package, I didn't have the latest types. Updating that package and changing `useRouterMatch` to `useRouteMatch` seems to have fixed the problem.